# UIView debugging

Tags: ios

What would people recommend to assist with UIView debugging?

Ideally, I'd like something along the lines of Firebug on Firefox - i.e. with visual information such as the width and height of your UIViews. However, the best solution so far seems to be this article posted in Dec 2008:

```
http://ramin.firoozye.com/2008/12/11/easy-uiview-debugging-on-the-iphone/
```

Is there a better solution - what else would people suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the randomcolor message handy in addition to NSStringfromCGRect(). Ref: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/05/visual-view-debugging/

Also read the comments of the post. Find excellent DCIntrospect - https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect

Comment: Thanks - DCIntrospect looks very handy.